# django: testing at different time

Tags: django, testing, time

I'd like to test a django app that renders a page depends on when it is accessed.

- If it is accessed within business hour, it will render "It's working time!".
- If not within business hour, it will render "It's holiday!"

I am using **django 1.7.1**. e.g django app name: *dogmatix*.

Here are my snippets.

`$ python manage.py startapp dogmatix`

`$ vim project/settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'dogmatix',
    )
```

`$ vim project/urls.py'

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^dogmatix/', include('dogmatix.urls')),
    )
```

`$ vim dogmatix/urls.py`

```
from dogmatix import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    )
```

`$ vim dogmatix/views.py`

```
import datetime

from django.http import HttpResponse

OPEN_TIME = datetime.time(9,0)
CURRENT_TIME = datetime.datetime.now().time()
CLOSE_TIME = datetime.time(17,0)

def index(request):
    if OPEN_TIME < CURRENT_TIME and CURRENT_TIME < CLOSE_TIME:
        return HttpResponse("It's working time!")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("It's holiday!")
```

And here's my test code:

`$ vim dogmatix/tests.py`

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client

class TestHoliday(TestCase):

    def test_url_holiday(self):
        response = self.client.get('/dogmatix/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertContains(response, 'holiday')
```

My test code above will be succeed if it was run between 9.00 - 17.00 Other than that will be failed. How to improve my test code so that it will be succeed whenever I run the test code?

Answer (score 1):

For a start, you code is *broken*. CURRENT_TIME will never change as long as the server process is running. If you start the server up at 9am, CURRENT_TIME will always be 9am.

You should define a function, `get_current_time`, which returns `datetime.datetime.now().time()`, and call that from the view.

Now, in your test, you can monkey-patch that - either manually, or using the excellent `mock` library - to return the time of your choosing.

Comment: I have defined `CURRENT_TIME` as `datetime.datetime.now().time()` at `dogmatix/views.py` And how to use this `mock` library? Where to patch?

Comment: As I said you need to use a *function* that returns the time, not a constant.

Comment: OK. How do you think about this test code? https://gist.github.com/za/2a217c47582737f88259 I created now() function which returns datetime.datetime.now() value.

Comment: I commented on the gist.